# How do I display the X-Spam headers in an Outlook 2010 mail folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, spam-prevention

I have two sets of spam scores stored in message headers, the first group is set by our trusty old mfiltro "spam box":

```
X-VRSPAM-DESCRIPTION: legit
X-VRSPAM-SCORE: 40.00
```

The second group is set by Spambayes working locally (the message is removed from the inbox, headers are added, and the message is inserted into 'clean-inbox'):

```
X-Spambayes-Classification: unsure
X-Spambayes-Spam-Probability: 0.88
X-Spambayes-Level: ********
X-Spambayes-MailId: 234d90cb-8478-422d-8341-e8688598a8e9@EXCHANGE1.ortdaktaet.intern
```

How would I go about adding one of these fields as a column in my spam folder so I can get a visual overview of how the filters are doing?  (Note: I'm not asking how to create a mail filter/rule to sort these emails).

I've searched google but only found people having lots of trouble, recipes for Outlook 2003, and opaque .cnf files and registry hacks for specific Exchange spam fields.

I can create a column with the name of the header field, but it doesn't show any content (I've turned of cached mode and restarted).

Am I naive in thinking that this ought to be easy..?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you can't! Outlook is PANTS, especially at showing the innards of emails and views. The best I can think of (cant test it just now) is to use a rule to set categories and use those in your view.

Comment: How disappointing.. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late for you but you can take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895091. This artikle is about to add the SCL level to a column in Outlook. I have seen this working and pretty sure you can use this technic to show other smtp headers.

Comment: Broken link. KB Article gone, but this is similar: https://www.petri.com/display_scl_level_in_outlook_2003

Comment: archived: https://web.archive.org/web/20131203082313/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895091

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for an answer to almost this exact issue, and since I got it working, I thought I would share this information for those future wayward souls who end up here.

Specifically, I was wanting to display the SpamAssassin's *x-spam-score* as a column. While this is for Outlook 2010, your process should be similar.

1. I downloaded and installed [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/download.htm).
2. I used [the viewsenderaddress.cfg extension file from
   HowTo-Outlook](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/viewsenderaddress.htm) as the basis for my CFG, since I knew this worked.
3. I used [this MSDN article as a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842185%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
4. Using OutlookSpy, I opened the IMessage to view the message information. I found that the original cfg was using a PT_UNICODE and so was the information I wanted, so I figured a straight swap wouldn't be a problem.
5. I found that "NmidInteger=" wasn't working for my item, so I switched to using the NmidPropSet and NmidString ID that I found in OutlookSpy.

I followed the same installation instructions and everything worked for me, YMMV.

Here is the relevant section:

```
[Properties]
Property01=XSpamScore
[Property.XSpamScore]
Type=30
NmidPropSet = {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
NmidString = x-spam-score
DisplayName = X-Spam-Score
```

Edit: Just a note -- you'll want to update the other naming references in the rest of the file as well, like the description and the "MessageClass=IPM.Note." value, etc.

Comment: Tried your recipe, but I can't get it to work.  OutlookSpy says the info I require (X-Spam-Level) is in PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS_W as type PT_UNICODE.  But that tag is the entire set of headers, how do I get just the X-Spam-Level line from it?